# mat-step onclick event function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

wondering if it is possible to have a click event for the mat-step button. For each mat-step button, I would like to add a `(click)` event which calls a `method`. In other words, the mat-step button acts like a regular button.

This is the mat-step:
https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

This is my code:

```
<mat-step>
<ng-template matStepLabel (click) = "createView()">Output</ng-template>
</mat-step>
```

I get this error:

> Template parse errors:
>    Event binding click not emitted by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the event name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("eateView()" >Output-->

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So, I just ran into this problem and the easy fix is to wrap the actual content of the step label in a p tag and add the click event there. For your example, it'd be:

```
<mat-step>
  <ng-template matStepLabel>
    <p (click)="createView()">Output</p>
  </ng-template>
</mat-step>
```

Alternatively, and much more powerfully, you can hook into the selectionChange event in the parent stepper component like so:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
```

The event emitted has the following properties: https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/api#StepperSelectionEvent

Comment: If I add click event on p tag, it will only work for <p>, not the entire mat-step button. Need better solution

Comment: Correct, the p tag version was my first fix but the selectionChange event was by far the better solution when I realized that only the p tag was affected. I didn't want to remove the p tag version when I edited though.

Comment: A problem with the second solution is that it only triggers when selection is changed. If something needs to work when the user clicks the same step again then the first solution would be better.

Answer (score 3):

After Step event. This was painful for me to figure out. When you land on the new step and you want to fire an event. Do the following.

Add (animationDone)

```js
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper (animationDone)="selectionChange(stepper)">
```

This will fire after the step is finished. And will give you the index of the new step you are on!

Comment: Well now that was interesting.  Worked like a champ, thanks

Answer (score 2):

For those who also want to add click event listener to the stepper even if user click the current step (which won't trigger selectionChange event):

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('ngAfterViewInit is triggered');
        this.fadeOut = false;
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll('mat-step-header');
        console.log('elements: ', elements);
        if (elements) {
            elements.forEach((e, i) => {
                console.log('e', i, ': ', e);
                if (i === 0) {
                    this.ele0 = e;
                    this.click0 = e.addEventListener('click', () => this.function(i));
                }
                else if (i === 1) {
                    this.ele1 = e;
                    this.click1 = e.addEventListener('click', () => this.function(i));
                }
                else if (i === 2) {
                    this.ele2 = e;
                    this.click2 = e.addEventListener('click', () => this.function(i));
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to assign each listener to a unique value, you can just remove the if condition. But it is recommended as you can remove those listeners on destroy.

Answer (score 0):

(selectionChange) event triggered after stepper change, want to call function before selectionChange.

Below code working for me, Try this it will work for entire mat-step button (because of custom css, you can add css for span too).

```
.mat-step-custom-click {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 130px; // as per your need
    height: 72px; // as per your need
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


<mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
        <div class="mat-step-custom-click" (click)="justTesting()">
            <span>YOUR LABEL</span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-step>


justTesting(){
   if( stepper.selectedIndex ){ // you can check stepper index
      let isValid = this.CheckValidations(yourData); // check your validations
      stepper.selected.completed = isValid;
      if( isValid ){
       doSomething(); // call your function
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Event emitted when the selected step has changed.

```
@Output()
selectionChange: EventEmitter<StepperSelectionEvent>
```

[API reference for Angular CDK stepper](https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/api#CdkStepper)

- Code: [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-demo-with-selection-change?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
- Demo: [Output](https://angular-mat-stepper-demo-with-selection-change.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score -3):

Just for a suggestion try this instead of `ng-template` use `div` or `span`
The event is firing I think. Let try this once and let me know.

The error tells something like that ng-template not firing as a event.

```
<mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
    You are now done.
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
```

Here is an example Iam copied from you send link. Let try this button

Comment: no luck: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgSwitchCase -> TemplateRef]:

Comment: this was after i changed ng-template to div and also tried span

Comment: Hey try this one   <button mat-button (click)="method()">Sample</button>

Comment: I currently have the solution that you provided. However, I am wanting to not use a second button. With the mat-step, those are buttons. I want to add the function call to that mat-step button, and not create an additional button.

Comment: See your question  if it is possible to have a click event for the mat-step button. It is solved. your question

Comment: yes, for "<mat-step>". I am referring to the buttons that you click to get to each step of the mat-step layout